# How to proof that nested intervals are an equivalent relation?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, relations, equivalence-relations

I want to show that a relation on the space of all sequences of nested intervals is an equivalence relation.

> Definition: Let $[a_n,b_n]_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $[c_n,d_n]_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be two "sequences of nested intervals".
>
> Define: $[a_n,b_n]_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\simeq [c_n,d_n]_{n\in\mathbb{N}} :\Leftrightarrow \forall n\in\mathbb{N}: a_n\leq d_n \wedge c_n\leq b_n $

with the Definiton for nested Intervalls:

> **Definition**: Let $[a_n,b_n]$ be sequence of Intervalls. We call it nested Intervall $:\Leftrightarrow$a) and b)
>
> a) $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}: a_n\leq a_{n+1}$ and $b_{n+1}\leq b_n $
>
> b) $\{b_n-a_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a nullsequence

**Proof:**

*Reflexive relation:*

Let $[a_n,b_n]_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of nested intervals.
Because $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}: a_n\leq b_n$ follows  $[a_n,b_n]_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\simeq [a_n,b_n]_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$

*Symmetric Relation:*

Let  $[a_n,b_n]_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\simeq [c_n,d_n]_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.
$\Leftrightarrow \forall n\in\mathbb{N}a_n\leq d_n \wedge c_n\leq b_n$

We have to show, that  $[c_n,d_n]_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\simeq [a_n,b_n]_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, wich meens  $c_n\leq b_n \wedge  a_n\leq d_n$.
This follows immediately.

*Transitive relation:*

Let  $[a_n,b_n]_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\simeq [c_n,d_n]_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and  $[c_n,d_n]_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\simeq [e_n,f_n]_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$

$\Leftrightarrow  \forall n\in\mathbb{N}: a_n\leq d_n \wedge c_n\leq b_n \wedge c_n\leq f_n \wedge e_n\leq d_n $

...?

//edit// I can show that there is at least one $a_n \leq s \leq b_n$ for every 'nested intervall' quite simple... maybe i should use that fact?

...

> I just dont see how to mange the transitive part. I think it cant be too hard.
> Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ae you sure it is true? Take the sequence of constant intervals: for all $n$, $[a_n,b_n]=[0,5]$, $[c_n, d_n]=[1,2]$, $[e_n, f_n]=[3,4]$. Don't we have $[a_n,b_n]\simeq [c_n,d_n]$ and $[a_n,b_n]\simeq [e_n,f_n]$, yet not $[c_n,d_n]\simeq [e_n,f_n]$?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for ur answer. Those Example you gave, do not sattice  the definiton of nested intervalls (wich i add above). $[a,b]_n$ with constant $a,b$ arent nullsequences.

Comment: What about $[a_n,b_n] = [0,\frac{2}{n}]$, $[c_n,d_n] = [\frac{1}{n},\frac{4}{n}]$, and $[e_n,f_n] = [\frac{3}{n},\frac{5}{n}]$? Then $[a_n,b_n]\simeq[c_n,d_n]$ and $[c_n,d_n]\simeq[e_n,f_n]$, but $[a_n,b_n]\not\simeq[e_n,f_n]$.

Comment: Hi, Joey Zou! Thanks for our answer. This Examples do not sattify the part a) of the definiton. See $\frac{1}{n}\not\leq\frac{1}{n+1}$. The lower sequence $a_n$ must bei rising and the upper sequence $b_n$ must be declining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true. I'll show transitivity. Define the relation between sequences of closed intervals as:
$$\begin{align}
([a_n,b_n])_{n\in\Bbb N} \simeq ([c_n,d_n])_{n\in\Bbb N} \iff & \forall n\in\Bbb N: \\
&\quad a_n \le d_n, \text{ and }\tag{i} \\
&\quad c_n\le b_n.\tag{ii}
\end{align}$$
A *sequence of nested intervals* is a sequence with the properties (a) and (b). These properties imply that there is a unique point $L$ in the intersection of the intervals, which moreover equals the sup of the left endpoints, the inf of the right endpoints, and the limit of both endpoint sequences:

> *Any sequence of nested intervals $([a_n,b_n])_{n\in\Bbb N}$ converges to a limit $L$, in several ways*:
>   $$\begin{align}\tag{$\dagger$}\\
> L &= \lim_n a_n = \sup_n a_n\\
> &= \lim_n b_n = \inf_n b_n \\
> &= \text{the unique element of }\bigcap_n [a_n,b_n].
> \end{align}$$

This is fairly well known; proof or reference on request.

Claim: $\simeq$-related sequences of nested intervals converge to the same limit:

> *For sequences of nested intervals $([a_n,b_n])_{n\in\Bbb N}$, $([c_n,d_n])_{n\in\Bbb N}$,*
>   $$if  ([a_n,b_n])_{n\in\Bbb N} \simeq ([c_n,d_n])_{n\in\Bbb N}
> ,\, then 
> \, \lim_n a_n = \lim_n c_n = \lim_n b_n = \lim_n d_n.\tag{*}$$

Indeed, given such sequences, let $L=\lim_n a_n$; then we have:
$$\begin{align}
L = \lim_n a_n &\le \lim_n d_n\tag{by (i)} \\
&= \lim_n c_n\tag{by ($\dagger$)} \\
&\le \lim_n b_n\tag{by (ii)} \\
&= L.\tag{by ($\dagger$)} \\
\end{align}$$

Finally,

> *Given sequences of nested intervals*
>   $$([a_n,b_n])_{n\in\Bbb N} \simeq ([c_n,d_n])_{n\in\Bbb N} \simeq ([e_n,f_n])_{n\in\Bbb N},\, 
> $$
>   *we have, for every $m\in\Bbb N$,* 
>   $$
> a_m \le f_m \text{ and } e_m\le b_m\tag{$result$};
> $$
>   *therefore,* 
>   $$
> ([a_n,b_n])_{n\in\Bbb N} \simeq ([e_n,f_n])_{n\in\Bbb N}. 
> $$

By hypothesis, all six endpoint sequences converge to the same limit $L$, which also equals the $\sup$s and $\inf$s of left-and right-hand endpoint sequences respectively. Given $m$, we have, by (*), $$a_m \le \sup_n a_n = L = \inf_n f_n \le f_m,$$and similarly, $$e_m \le \sup_n e_n = L = \inf_n b_n \le b_m;$$hence the *result*. But that *result*, true for all $m$, says exactly that $\simeq$ holds between the sequences $([a_n, b_n])$ and $([e_n, f_n])$, so the conclusion follows.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: You're welcome. It's an interesting proposition. Where's it from?

Comment: I was thinking about the fact constructing $\mathbb{R}$ as an equivalent-relation in the space of nested intervalls ... because i wasnt able to find something about it, i tried to bulid it myself.

Comment: Well, you found a nice one.

Comment: I like it, too ;)